# nodejs don't close file handle on windows?

Tags: node.js

After running the following code, the file handle is still opened on Windows, how to close it?

```
var Name="1.mp4";
var inp = fs.createReadStream("Temp/" + Name);
var out = fs.createWriteStream("Video/" + Name);
inp.pipe(out);
inp.on("end", function() {
  fs.unlink("Temp/" + Name, function (){
    out.close();
    console.log("unlink this file:",Name );
  });
});
```

[screen shot: file handle not colsed on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p8pY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close `inp` too not just `out`. You can do this by calling `inp.close();` at the same point you already call `out.close();`.

Also you could simply move the file with

```
fs.rename("Temp/" + Name, "Video/" + Name, function() {
    console.log("Renamed:", Name)
});
```

rather than rewriting the file.

Comment: Oh, yes, fs.rename is better.